# Power BI DAX Calculate MOD Function with related table column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to use the MOD function between a measure from my fact table and a column in my dimension table.

I have a measure for single sales, and in my product table I have a column that counts how many singles are in a box. I'd like a measure that calculates the remainder between the singles and units per box.

One caveat is that I did not create the Singles measure and I don't have access to the DAX formula for it.

I've tried the following measure but I'm receiving an error shown below.

> Resource Governing: This DAX query uses more memory than the configured limit. The query — or calculations referenced by it — might be too memory-intensive to run. Either simplify the query or its calculations, or if using Power BI Premium, you may reach out to your capacity administrator to see if they can increase the per-query memory limit.

Any thoughts on how I should fix?

```
_Singles Sold =

VAR Units_Per_Box = MAX('Product'[Units Per Box]) 
VAR Singles = [Singles Sold] 

RETURN
    MOD(Singles, Units_Per_Box)
```

Comment: what is the code of Singles Sold